# Adding a new name and score to an existing 2D array + I/O streams?

Tags: java, arrays, stream, storage

So I have a Sudoku game and I'm trying to implement a High Score system **(Records the top 5 players)** for it based on the times of the players. The lower the time, the higher the rank in the High Score is. I have thought on how to make it through streams. However, I do not know how to add a **NEW** high score to my 2D array (`nametime[5][2]`). I can add one name and score, but I can't add a new one when I play my game again.

Variables:

```
    private String[][] nametime = new String[5][2];
    private String[] names = new String[5];
    private String[] times = new String[5];
```

Here's what I've done so far:

```
    //assigns values to names[] and times[]
    private void addNamesAndTimes(String name, String score){

        names[0] = name;
        times[0] = score;

        System.out.println("Player: " + name + " || " + "Time: " + score);
    }
```

I only assigned name and score to their first indices, `names[0]` and `times[0]` because this is where my problem is. I don't know how to keep adding names and scores to my arrays.

```
    //merges names[] and times[] array into one 2D array nametime[][]
    private String[][] mergeArrays(String[] a, String[] b){

        for(int i = 0; i < nametime.length; i++){
            nametime[i][0] = a[i];
            nametime[i][1] = b[i];
        }

        return nametime;
    }
```

I decided to merge my `names[]` and `times[]` arrays because I'm gonna do something with the `times[]` array later on. (Comparisons of scores)

```
public void createScoreFile(String name, String score){
    addNamesAndTimes(name, score);

    File file = new File("Scores.txt");

    try {
        if(!file.exists()){
            System.out.println("Creating new file...");
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fo);

        for(int i = 0; i < nametime.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < nametime[0].length; j++){
                ps.print(mergeArrays(names, times)[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            ps.println();
        }

        ps.close();

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This method is for creating my a file that stores my `nametime[][]` array

```
//reads the contents of the text file and outputs it back to nametime[][]
    public String[][] loadScoreFile(){

    File file = new File("Scores.txt");

    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

        for(int i = 0; i < nametime.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < nametime[i].length; j++){
                nametime[i][j] = scan.next();
            }  
        }

        System.out.println("Nametime Array:");
        for(int i = 0; i < nametime.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < nametime[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(nametime[i][j] + "\t");
            }  
            System.out.println();
        }

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return nametime;

}
```

This method is for reading my Score.txt file

```
//method for showing the table and frame
public void showFrame(){
        table = new JTable(loadScoreFile(), header);
        *other GUI stuff here*
}
```

I would appreciate anyone who can help me!

Edit: Here's to reiterate my problem once again. When I'm done playing the game, it should record the player name and score in the array and the .txt file. Then I close the game. When I open the game and finish playing again, it would have to store the name and score to the array and .txt file again. But in my case, that's not what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating a class that hold a player-time pair. Also, maybe use some Collections class to keep the results sorted.

Here's an example (using TreeSet to hold the results in ascending order of time):

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Test {
   static class Result implements Comparable<Result> {

      String name;
      int time;

      public Result(String name, int time) {
         this.name = name;
         this.time = time;
      }

      public int compareTo(Result o) {
         return this.time - o.time;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "Result [name=" + name + ", time=" + time + "]";
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SortedSet<Result> results = new TreeSet<Result>();
      results.add(new Result("a", 5));
      results.add(new Result("b", 3));
      results.add(new Result("c", 1));
      results.add(new Result("d", 15));
      results.add(new Result("e", 10));
      results.add(new Result("f", 8));
      results.add(new Result("g", 9));
      results.add(new Result("h", 11));
      results.add(new Result("i", 7));
      results.add(new Result("j", 20));

      Iterator<Result> it = results.iterator();
      int i = 0;
      while (it.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println(it.next());
         i++;
         if (i == 5) {
            break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Result [name=c, time=1]
Result [name=b, time=3]
Result [name=a, time=5]
Result [name=i, time=7]
Result [name=f, time=8]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I implement this with the streams still? Cos I can't think of anything that would store and remember the values I have already put.

Comment: You can use the same streams approach to save and load these.
 
Alternatively you could create a new class that has "results" as a field and declare it as serializable. This might be faster but the file will not be human-readable. You can check this link for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html

Comment: I appreciate it. Another question though, will the TreeSet be able to keep track of what has already been saved? For example, I play the game and the name + score is recorded. When I close the game and open it up again and I play (requiring another name and score), will the TreeSet still hold the previous name + score AND the current name + score?

Comment: If closing the game means exiting the application then you need to save the TreeSet contents and reload at the start of a new game.

Comment: If I save the contents of the TreeSet, I'll have to write it via the streams, right? Once I do that, how do I add NEW values to the SAVED TreeSet?

Comment: You can use reader(s)/writer(s) that do character I/O. Check: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html
You just call the add() method to add new elements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9729/discussion-between-taeyeon-and-masterf)